# How can I create dynamic jquery selectors?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-selectors

My workout routines index page looks like this.

```
<% @workout_routines.each do |routine| %>
<ul>
<li>Name: <%= routine.name %></li>
<li>Days: <%= routine.split_length %></li>
<li>Difficulty: <%= routine.difficulty %></li> 
<button class= "exercises" id= "<%= routine.id %>">View Exercises</button>
<div class= "workoutshow" id= "<%= routine.id %>"></div>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

When I click the exercises button, I want to append html to the workoutshow div for just the workout I clicked on, but I cannot figure out how to use string concatenation/interpolation inside a jquery selector. I tried things like

```
$(".workoutshow #${data.id}")
```

but so far no luck. Is there a proper way to do this? 
Also, here is the code in workoutshow.js, currently, for clarity.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".exercises").on('click', function(e) { 
    $.get("/workout_routines/" + e.target.id, function(data){ 
        debugger;
        $(".workoutshow").append("<li>" + "Category: " + data["category"] + "</li>")
            .append("<li>" + "Difficulty: " + data["difficulty"] + "</li>")
    })
}) 
})
```

Comment: try `$(".workoutshow #"+data.id) `

Comment: Ahhh okay made it work with a slight tweak of that: $("div#"+data.id + ".workoutshow")

Answer (score 0):

```
  /* json data to javascript json parser*/      
  var data = JSON.parse('<% @workout_routines %>');

  $('.exercises').click(function(){
        /* get '.exercises' index */
        var idx = $(this).index('.exercises');

        /* same index for '.workoutshow' use .eq()*/
        $('.workoutshow').eq(idx).append(
            "<li>" + 
                "Category: " + data[idx].category + 
            "</li>" +
            "<li>" + 
                "Difficulty: " +
                 data[idx].difficulty + 
            "</li>"
         );


    });
```

Comment: You need to add an explanation for what you have done and why.

Comment: class, name has an index and we can use it in eq. And I think '@workout_routines' is json, so I use JSON.parser.

Comment: Try editing your answer with an explanation so the OP and future readers can understand what you have done and learn from it.

Comment: i can't use english well that I could not explain it again.
Sorry. However, development and study were interesting and I answered.
Next time I will study English and not use Google translator
i will be able to give you a more accurate answer.
Thank you for your advice.